# Regex | Pegar separar grupo

Tags: c#, string, regex, html-tags

Essa tag repete mudando o conteúdo e gostaria de saber se tem como pegar cada conteúdo separadamente

```
    TextBox TXTTESTE = new TextBox();
    TextBox TXTTESTEDOIS = new TextBox();
    TextBox TXTTESTETRES = new TextBox();
    ListBox LBTESTE = new ListBox();
    MatchCollection TESTE = Regex.Matches(html, @"(<[^>]+>Alíquota<[^>]+><[^>]+>\d+\,\d+<[^>]+>)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    foreach (Match grupo in TESTE)
    {
         string strteste = grupo.Groups[0].Value;
         string strdoisteste = grupo.Groups[1].Value;
         string strtresteste = grupo.Groups[2].Value;
         LBTESTE.Items.Add(strteste);
         LBTESTE.Items.Add(strdoisteste);
         LBTESTE.Items.Add(strtresteste);
    }
```

Comment: Edite e coloque o exemplo da tag.

Comment: ele retorna "10,00" , "20,00" , "30,00"
"10,00" , "20,00" , "30,00"

Comment: Tem um software para rodar regex .Net que eu uso muito para testar regexes rapidamente quando preciso: [Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://rad-software-regular-expression-designer.software.informer.com/)

Comment: Vou melhorar a pergunta, o que tem dentro de html ?

Comment: Tem isso no HTML:
<td><label>Alíquota</label><span class="linha">18,00</span></td></tr><td><label>Alíquota</label><span class="linha">50,00</span></td></tr>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você quer resgatar somente os valores certo? Neste caso, você deve criar um grupo somente no valor:

```
<[^>]+>Alíquota<[^>]+><[^>]+>(\d+\,\d+)<[^>]+>
```

Note que estou colocando `\d+\,\d+` entre parenteses, para criar um grupo de captura.

Note também que eu removi os parenteses mais externos.

Depois é possível usar o foreach para iterar sobre as matches, e obter de cada uma, o grupo de captura que definimos anteriormente:

```
foreach (Match grupo in TESTE)
{
    LBTESTE.Items.Add(grupo.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

- `Groups[0]`: é o grupo de captura que equivale a toda a regex. No caso do HTML indicado por você são eles:

  - `<label>Alíquota</label><span class="linha">18,00</span>`
  - `<label>Alíquota</label><span class="linha">50,00</span>`
- `Groups[1]`: é o grupo de captura eu defini, usando parenteses. No caso do HTML indicado por você são eles:

  - `18,00`
  - `50,00`
- Outros grupos podem existir, numerados sequencialmente, para cada abre/fecha parenteses que forem encontrados na expressão regular.

Comment: quando eu capturo o grupo tem como eu definir o item1 / item2 / item3 em ordem ? posso usar eles quando eu quiser? sem ser na ordem que estão?

Comment: Deslculpa, não entendi... poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Você pode adicionar todos os valores em uma lista intermediária, antes de adicionar no list-box, assim pode fazer o que quiser.

Comment: é possivel adicionar um index no grupo e quando eu falar grupo.Groups[1/2/3].Value ele chama o valor Item1 / Item2 / Item3 se sim , como?

Comment: Na verdade tem como fazer isso para os matches, que no seu caso está na variável `TESTE`... assim: `TESTE[n].Groups[1].Value`, onde `n` é o índice que você vai usar: 0, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: gostaria tambem saber como funciona o metodo NextMatch()

Comment: Esse método é usado quando você tem um objeto Match, e quer pegar o próximo... usar o método `Regex.Matches` é o mesmo que usar `Regex.Match` e depois charmar `NextMatch` até não ter mais nenhum match.

Comment: Miguel voce me falou que eu posso chamar ´TESTE[].Groups[].Value´ mas ele só define o valor da regex

Comment: Então acho que eu realmente não entendi a sua pergunta.

Comment: Consegui arrumar removi os itens da lista e usei os que eu precisava muito obrigado, não estava pensando com muita clareza

Answer (score 1):

Tem sim. Você não está usando o conceito de grupos corretamente. Um grupo se define da seguinte forma:

```
(?<nome>.*?)
```

Para acessar:

```
foreach (Match grupo in TESTE) {
    grupo.Groups["nome"];
}
```

Comment: e depois que eu defini o grupo como eu divido ele?

Comment: Colocando a expressão dentro do parênteses, logo após o `>`.